# Failing to run xr package

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, xr

I have created two LaTeX files: `1.tex` and `2.tex`. First file contains a figure and I want to make a reference to that figure in the second file. I run pdfLaTeX several times (2-3) for both files. Sadly in return, in second file I get "`??`" sign instead of a respective label. When checking the Console Output for second file, it contains following lines:

> ```
> ...
> Package xr Warning: 
> No file 1.aux
> LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
> on input line 4.
> ...
> ```

Apparently something is going wrong during compilation. **How to fix this error?**

Contents of both `1.tex` and `2.tex` files are shown below. Both of these files are saved in same folder.

**`1.tex`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}

\begin{document}
My document No 1. And here you can see some chemical stuff: Figure~\ref{fig:Fig1}.
\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Fig1}
\caption{Some cheical stiff}
\label{fig:Fig1}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**And here is the `2.tex`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{1}

\begin{document}
My document No 1. And here you can see some chemical stuff: \ref{fig:Fig1}.

\end{document}
```

And here is what I see as an output for `2.tex`:
[image]

I have also copied the contents of the Console Output for both files and saved as Notepad `txt` files. Here are links for this files: [`1.txt`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-2Uq8IFdyk0dEJkcVc2NGtiNzA) and [`2.txt`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-2Uq8IFdyk0S1pScVZlbWdyd1U)

Comment: you have to run both files two times each with.

Comment: Are you redirecting the output or cleaning up after the compilation?

Comment: I run both files several times. I.e. I run 1.tex 2-3 times, then I run 2.tex 2-3 times. It doesn't seem to be working anyway.

Comment: I am not sure about how to redirect the output or clean up after the compilation. In the end I even don't close the files after compilation. I just minimize the respective windows.

Comment: Then show the log-files and the aux-files.

Comment: are the files in the same directory?  when you run latex on 2.tex it has to be able to input 1.aux so that file has to be in the input path, most easily in the same directory/

Comment: Where do I find the log-files and aux-files?

Comment: Yes the files are in the same directory

Comment: I have copied the text from Console Output for both files and saved them as a respective .txt notepad files (1.txt and 2.txt, respectively). Here are links to this files: [link1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-2Uq8IFdyk0dEJkcVc2NGtiNzA) and [link2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-2Uq8IFdyk0S1pScVZlbWdyd1U)

Comment: Both log-files say "No file 1.aux", so references can't work. If the messages don't disappear you are probably deleting the aux-files between the compilations.

Comment: you say it's not working but the log was clearly warning you that the it could not resolve the references, I even put it in all caps so you'd notice, you could have mentioned the warning in your question:-)  Package xr Warning: 
No file 1.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
 on input line 4.

Comment: Thanks for comments, @Ulrike, is there a way to distinguish why it is happening and resolve the issue?

Comment: Don't use `File` → `Remove Aux Files…`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @David, I have modified the question accordingly. Hope it will be more clear now

Comment: @Schweinebacke, I don't use it

Comment: You don't even need to run `pdflatex` two times for each file. After the first `pdflatex` run of `1.tex` you should already have `1.aux` with some lines, i.e., `\newlabel{fig:Fig1}{{1}{1}}` in the document folder. So if you run `pdflatex` for `2.tex` afterward you will immediately get: `My document No 1. And here you can see some chemical stuff: 1.`

Comment: as already stated there is nothing wrong with your files. just run latex on 1.tex and there will be a 1.aux in the current directory, then run 2.tex and the reference will work. if 1.aux is not generated in the current directory you have used a command line option to write it somewhere else, or deleted it using commands that you have not mentioned.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, thanks, now it works. Apparently I was running pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. When I have changed it to pdfLaTeX it started working. But does it mean I will not be able to create BibTeX references when using xr?

Comment: No, it won't. As long a you do not have an index or a bibliography, running MakeIndex or BibTeX results in errors. Nevertheless, the `aux` file is the same and the result is the same too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run bibtex on its own, e.g. through the typeset menu, at the end there is bibtex:

[image]

I wouldn't use the `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` script, it uses texify and this is quite a pain when errors occur. Also it is really not needed to run makeindex and bibtex all the time. But if you want to use it, you should remove in the preferences the `--clean` option (select the script you want to adjust and then click `edit`):

[image]

Comment: Is this Windows specific? Here, with Linux version of Texworks I do not have such an entry.